# aiohttp how do I retrieve peer certificate?

Tags: ssl-certificate, python-asyncio, aiohttp

I want to get the certificate hash. But I have no idea how to get the server peer certificate. Either in the request or response. The server I send the request to sets the `Connection close` header, so the retrieving the original ssl socket in the response doesn't work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Currently no way, sorry.
You can check a cert hash easy though: https://docs.aiohttp.org/en/stable/client_advanced.html#ssl-control-for-tcp-sockets

The following example uses SHA-256 fingerprint check:

```
fingerprint = b'...'  # should be 64 bytes length hash (256/8)

r = await session.get('https://example.com',
                      ssl=aiohttp.Fingerprint(fingerprint))
```

Comment: I found that example indeed. But I need to send the hash as part of my request. I'm porting pywinrm to asyncio and apparentlly you need (should) to send the certificate hash for Kerberos.

Answer (score 1):

I've come up with this solution/hack

```
import aiohttp


class WrappedResponseClass(aiohttp.ClientResponse):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(WrappedResponseClass, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self._peer_cert = None

    async def start(self, connection, read_until_eof=False):
        try:
            self._peer_cert = connection.transport._ssl_protocol._extra['ssl_object'].getpeercert(True)
        except Exception:
            pass
        return await super(WrappedResponseClass, self).start(connection, read_until_eof)

    @property
    def peer_cert(self):
        return self._peer_cert



session = aiohttp.ClientSession(otherargs..., response_class=WrappedResponseClass)
```

Comment: It is really a hack.
aiohttp has no commitment to support it.

Comment: Downvoting because the code accesses an internal slot of both the transport and the underlying ssl_protocol, so it cannot be recommended for production code. Combined with the statement of the aiohttp maintainer that it is an unsupported hack, it is not a solution a StackOverflow answer should advertise.

Comment: Very understandable that aiohttp is not going to support it. Going to add a feature request for a decent way of doing this.

Comment: So far this is the only way I've found that works. Versioning the dependencies might resolve the internal access concerns, although upgrading in future years becomes more work.

Answer (score 0):

The following works for me with aiohttp 3.8.3:

```
async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as session:
    r = await session.get('https://bbc.com')
    cert = r.connection.transport.get_extra_info('peercert')
```

Comment: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'transport'

Comment: This is why I started https://github.com/aio-libs/aiohttp/pull/7181, it must be done right after the connection is established.

Comment: This returns an empty dict if the context does not use default certification verification.